# Computing the unit vector for a generalised helix

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors, curves, frenet-frame

The space curve $$\mathbf x (t) = \begin{pmatrix} \cosh t \\ \sinh t \\ t \end{pmatrix}$$ is an example of a generalized helix, meaning that its tangent vector makes a constant angle $\theta$ with a fixed unit vector $\mathbf A$, so that $\mathbf T \cdot \mathbf A = \cos  \theta$.  Find the unit vector $\mathbf A$ in this case and the angle $\theta$.

Attempt:

I could write the unit vector $\mathbf A = \cos \theta \mathbf T + \sin \theta \mathbf B$ since then the magnitude is one and the condition $\mathbf T \cdot \mathbf A = \cos \theta$ is easily recovered. Then sub in expressions for $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf B$, thereby expressing $\mathbf A$ in terms of the basis vectors in Euclidean space, but this doesn't help with finding the angle.
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You have that $\mathbf{T}(t)$ and $\mathbf{A}$, so just substitute this back into your defining equation.

Comment: Hi Travis, I have $\mathbf T (t)$ in terms of the Euclidean basis, but $\mathbf A$ I have in terms of the frenet-serret basis. So, I subbed in $\mathbf T$ and $\mathbf B$ into my equation for $\mathbf A$ and then took the dot product but that doesn't seem to help. Or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: That's even better, since $\bf{T}$ is orthogonal to $\bf{N}$ and $\bf{B}$, so $\cos \theta$ is just the coefficient of $\bf A$ in the Frenet-Serret basis (at any point).

Comment: What coefficient do you mean here? The $\mathbf A$ I am working with is $\mathbf A = \cos \theta \mathbf T + \sin \theta \mathbf B$. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I understand your explanation now, you haven't actually found $\bf A$.

Comment: yes, I constructed $\mathbf A$ like that because almost by inspection its modulus is $1$ and it recovers the equation $\mathbf T \cdot A = \cos \theta$. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Yes, I've written an answer which gives a hint, and which really amounts to making just one additional observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing gives that (in the Euclidean basis)
$${\bf T} = \frac{{\bf x}'}{|{\bf x}'|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\tanh t, 1, \text{sech} t).$$

Also in the Euclidean basis, decompose $${\bf A} = (a, b, c).$$ Now, we know that $\cos \theta = {\bf T} \cdot {\bf A}$ is constant, so $$({\bf T} \cdot {\bf A})' = 0.$$ If we expand this quantity in the Euclidean basis using the above expressions, we get constraints on $a, b, c$, and these together with the fact that $|{\bf A}| = 1$ determines $\bf A$ up to sign.

Comment: So, $(\mathbf T \cdot \mathbf A)' = \mathbf T ' \cdot \mathbf A = 0 \Rightarrow a/c = \sinh t$ together with the fact that $|\mathbf A| =1  \Rightarrow \sqrt{c^2 \cosh^2 t + b^2} = 1$

Comment: Since $\bf A$ is constant, its components must also be constant.

Comment: If $\mathbf A$ is constant, $(\mathbf T \cdot \mathbf A)' = \mathbf T' \cdot \mathbf A = 0$. Computing $\mathbf T'$ and taking the dot product with $\mathbf A$ gives the constraint $asech^2t = c $sech$ t \tanh t \Rightarrow a/c = \sinh t $.  Then I rearranged this for $a$ and subbed into the unity modulus condition and that gave me $c^2 \cosh^2 t + b^2 = 1$.

Comment: It's true that $\frac{a}{c} = \sinh t$ if $c \neq 0$. Whether $c = 0$ or not, we can still say that $a = c \sinh t$. Now, $a$ is constant, so the RHS is constant---what does this tell us about $a$ and $c$?

Comment: That would mean $a$ and $c$ are both zero, since we could vary the RHS without affecting the LHS which would not make sense given their established equality. Is that right?

Comment: So then $b = \pm 1$ and $\mathbf A = \pm \mathbf e_y$

Comment: Yes, exactly, and now you can substitute to find $\cos \theta$ and then $\theta$.

Comment: Sorry ignore that last message about moving discussion to chat, clicked on it by accident (now deleted it). That would make $\theta = \pi/4$.

Comment: Yes, exactly (or $\theta = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$ if you choose the other solution for $\bf A$).

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it helpful. In general, if you're given an expression in components, it's sometimes useful to write all of the applicable objects in components and compute in components too.